# Find shortest distance between points of two arrays with scipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scipy

I have two arrays `centroids` and `nodes`

I need to find the shortest distance of each point in `centroids` to any point in `nodes`

The output for `centroids`  is following

```
array([[12.52512263, 55.78940022],
       [12.52027731, 55.7893347 ],
       [12.51987146, 55.78855611]])
```

The output for `nodes`  is following

```
array([[12.5217378, 55.7799275],
       [12.5122589, 55.7811443],
       [12.5241664, 55.7843297],
       [12.5189395, 55.7802709]])
```

I use the following code to get the shortest distance

```
shortdist_from_centroid_to_node = np.min(cdist(centroids,nodes))
```

However, this is the output I get (I should get 3 lines of output)

```
Out[131]: 3.0575613850140956e-05
```

Can anyone specify what the problem is here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you doing np.min it return the minimal value of the 2d-array.
You want the minimum value for each centroids.

```
shortest_distance_to_centroid = [min(x) for x in cdist(centroids,nodes)]
```

To have the associate index one way would be to get the index of the corresponding value. Another is to write a custom min() function that also return the index (so you parse the list only once)

```
[(list(x).index(min(x)), min(x)) for x in cdist(centroids,nodes)]  # the cast list() is needed because numpy array don't have index methods
```

solution with a custom function:

```
def my_min(x):
       current_min = x[0]
       current_index = [1]

       for i, v in enumerate(x[1:]):
              if v < current_min:
                     current_min = v
                     current_index = i + 1
       return (current_index, current_min)

[my_min(x) for x in cdist(centroids,nodes)]
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue! Do you know if it is also possible to get the index number of the node with the shortest distance to the centroid?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you need is just add an arg called `axis`, just like this:

```py
shortdist_from_centroid_to_node = np.min(cdist(centroids,nodes), axis=1)
```

As for the meaning of the axis arg, you could refer to [numpy.min](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html#numpy.amin). All in all you need minimum on each row rather than on the whole matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong your code says you are trying to access the `min` value hence you are getting a single value. remove `np.min()` try:

```
shortdist_from_centroid_to_node = cdist(centroids,nodes)
```